# Observers property in TComponent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, livebindings

Hi Delphi XE2 [TComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TComponent) has a new ["Observers" property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TComponent.Observers). Unfortunately the help entries for this are empty. Does anybody know what this new property is good for and how to use it? 
Edit: Well i know that it is related to LiveBindings, but I would love to know a bit more about it, and since I have no access to XE2 source code, I can't investigate myself.

Comment: [Stefan Glienke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587106/stefan-glienke) has also a blog post mentioning the `implemention of the observer pattern into TComponent` in Delphi XE2 [here](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/09/dharp-bindings-vs-livebindings.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is related to LiveBindings. A rather cool but extensive subject, explained in the new [DocWiki for XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio).

Comment: sorry Rudy, but the DocWiki isn't really helpful with respect to my question. I am quite aware of LiveBindings, but have my problems really understanding what's behind them, and how they are implemented. Therefore the background of my question is how they are related to LiveBindings.

Comment: Hmmm... I see that, indeed, the role of the observer is not explained. I guess I'll remove my answer in a while.

Comment: "Therefore the background of my question is how they are related to LiveBindings." If that is the case, it would have helped to put that information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi implementation of the observer pattern is explained here:

http://blogs.teamb.com/joannacarter/2004/06/30/690

I'll update the answer with more details as soon as I've had a chance to look at the source code.

Comment: This is interesting but it seems to be unrelated to the new TComponent.Observers property

Answer (score 2):

The [Delphi XE7 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Observers) now goes much deeper into the details of the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fringe_characters#September_.28The_Observer.29)s:

> Observers is a read-only property that returns the TObservers added to
>   the TComponent, in order to use the notifications provided by the
>   observers either with LiveBindings or for the developers' own
>   purposes.

*Note that the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fringe_characters#September_.28The_Observer.29) in Fringe can be seen on the scene of many [Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_%28disambiguation%29)-related events.*

---

Side note:

Observers might also be able to detect situations where a [EProgrammerNotFound exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084120/eprogrammernotfound-exception-in-delphi) must be thrown by the RTL.